# Spreading a single build over multiple slaves

Tags: hudson, master-slave

I want to write an ant script that is distributed over multiple slaves. I don't understand exactly how the hudson system works, but it seems to simply run the whole of one type of build on a single slave. I would like multiple slaves to run in parallel to do my testing. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split your testing job into several jobs. 1 job per slave. Your build will then trigger all testing jobs at the same time. If you need to run an additional job, you can use the [join trigger plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Join+Plugin).

The release notes for Hudson 1.377 list a new feature:

> Queue/execution model is extended to
>   allow jobs that consume multiple
>   executors on different nodes

Don't know what that exactly means. But I will definitely have a look.